# Write response from API to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an API response like this:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": {
    "total": 5
  }
}
```

I want to write the `total` value from the response above, `5`, to my HTML. When I create the js file to get the response the result in HTML is empty.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<div class="inner">
  <h3 id="total"></h3>
  <p>Total</p>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(value) {
        //append each row data to datatable
        var row = value.total
        $('#total').append(row);
      });
    }
  })
})
```

Do you know how to show the `total` that I want from the API in HTML? Thank you

Comment: Do not use `append()` but jQuery's `text()` function or `innerHTML` if you don't want to use any framework. You can append DOM elements but this is just string/number so `text()` is enough for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an `each()` loop here as the response is a single object, not an array. As such you can access the `data.value` and set it as the `text()` of `#total`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      var total = response.data.total;
      $('#total').text(total);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` to insert value

```js
var a= {
   "status": 200,
   "message": "OK",
   "data": {
   "total": 5
    }
 };
 document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML=a.data.total
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  <div class="inner">
          <h3 id="total"></h3>
          <p>Total</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* $(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        total = total + response[i].data.total;
      }
      $('#total').text(total);
    }
  })
}) */
// for ex.: -
const data = [{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": {
    "total": 5
  }
}, {
  "status": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": {
    "total": 5
  }
}, {
  "status": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": {
    "total": 5
  }
}];
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  total = total + data[i].data.total;
}
$('#total').text(total);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<div class="inner">
  <h3 id="total"></h3>
  <p>Total</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I think it should be work

```
 $('#total').append(`<p>${row}</p>`)
    {
  "status": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": {
    "total": 5
  }
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<div class="inner">
  <h3 id="total"></h3>
  <p>Total</p>
</div>
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var row = data.data.total
        $('#total').text(row);
      });
    }
  })
})
```